# Why does my program not work with large numbers?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that find the largest prime factor of 600851475143. It works perfectly with smaller numbers ( until 10000), but no further than that.
How can I change it? The program does not give any error or end itself, but simply does not output anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime( unsigned long long int num);


int main() {
    unsigned long  long int  m = 600851475143;
    std::vector<int> pfactors;
    pfactors.reserve(100000000);
    for (long long int  i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
         if (isPrime(i) == true) {
             if (m % i == 0) {
                 pfactors.push_back(i);
             }
        }
      }
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = pfactors.begin(); it != pfactors.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
    }




bool isPrime(unsigned long long int num)
{
    if (num < 2) 
        return false;


    if (num > 2 && (num % 2) == 0)
        return false;


    for (unsigned long long int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {

        if ((num % i) == 0) 
        {

            return false; 
        }
    }


    return true; 
}
```

Comment: change std::vector<int> pfactors; to   std::vector<unsigned long long> pfactors;

Comment: You are not patient enough -  A slow algorithm may take hours, days, weeks, ...

Comment: btw your `isPrime` function is sub-optimal. You should search divisors until square root of number.

Comment: @DieterLücking how can I make it quicker then?

Comment: Hint: you only need to check a candidate to be not divisible by primes that are less than a candidate

Comment: plus to get a list of primes, it's better to compute them using sieve of Erathostemes (not sure of the spelling)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why until the square root of the number?

Comment: because the divisor d may not be greater than x/d

Comment: I solved a lot of project Euler problems, believe me prime computation is the base (I did it in python to avoid the large integer issue)

Comment: @Serge So, I need to check a number to be not divisible by the primes less than that number?

Comment: Yes, actually. but even limiting tests to only previously found primes would drastically speed up your search

Answer (score 1):

Answers provided by @DanyalImran and @Jean-FrançoisFabre are both incorrect.
It is co-incidence, that 600851475143 is a product of 71, 839, 1471 and 6857 and all divisors are less than sqrt(num).
What if the number in the OP would be 60085147514**9** (the prime number)?

Thus we need to search a full range [2,num], not the range [2,sqrt(num)].

So, here is what I got after a few attempts to make the search optimized using both Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to precompute a vector of prime flags and memorizing previously found primes.

Although the Sieve of Eratosthenes is really a fastest way to find all primes in some specified range (it has no division operations, only multiplications that are times faster than divisions), this approach can't help much as it does not eliminate the need to loop through the vector to find elements marked as primes and then divide the number in question with the found prime (I intentionally replaced `vector<bool>` with `vector<char>` in the @Jean-FrançoisFabre's implementation to avoid possible 'bit-packed' implementation of a `vector<bool>` as a bit position in a vector calculation is definitely more expensive than a char position calculation).

The time I get this way to solve the task in OP for 150212868857 prime is ~7:05 minutes on my 1.4GHz AMD:

```
150212868857

real    7m5.156s
user    7m5.063s
sys 0m0.008s
```

The attempt to memorize all previously found primes to speedup the `isPrime()` test is even worse, so I did not give it a chance to finish. This explained by the same necessity to iterate through a vector of primes and it is even more expensive due to amount of data to be read from memory.

The final variant is just an iteration of the candidate divisor in the range from 3 to `num` with step 2 and calling the `isPrime` only when `num` is even to candidate. This approach shows the same time as previous plus-minus a few seconds. Thus, the access to a vector element appears to be as expensive as a division as soon as the math used fits into native registers of a modern CPU.

However, when the number in question is not prime (as in the OP) there is still a place for optimization that allows to shorten the search time.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//#define SIEVE
vector<char> primeFlagger;

void initSieve(unsigned long long int limit) {
    unsigned long long int root = (unsigned long long int)(sqrt(limit));
    primeFlagger = vector<char>(root+1,true);
    primeFlagger[0] = primeFlagger[1] = false;

    for(unsigned long long int j=2; j<=root; j++)
    {
        if(primeFlagger[j])
        {
            for(unsigned long long int k=j; (k*j)<=root; k++)
            {
                primeFlagger[j*k]=false;
            }
        }
    }
}

#ifdef SIEVE
bool isPrime(unsigned long long int num)
{
    if (num <= 2)
        return true;

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
        return false;

    unsigned sqr = (unsigned)sqrt(num);
    for(unsigned i = 3; i <= sqr; i+=2) {
        if (primeFlagger[i] && num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
#else
bool isPrime(unsigned long long int num)
{
    if (num <= 2)
        return true;

    if ((num % 2) == 0)
        return false;

    unsigned sqr = (unsigned)sqrt(num);
    for(unsigned i = 3; i <= sqr; i+=2) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
#endif

int main() {
    unsigned long long int  m = 600851475143;//150212868857;//600851475149;
    std::vector<unsigned long long int> pfactors;

#ifdef SIEVE
    initSieve(m);
#endif

    if (m % 2 == 0) {
        do {
            m /= 2;
        } while (m % 2 == 0);
        pfactors.push_back(2);
    }

    for (long long int i = 3; i <= m; i+=2) {
        if (m % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
            do {
                m /= i;
            } while (m % i == 0);
            pfactors.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for (vector<unsigned long long int>::iterator it = pfactors.begin(); it != pfactors.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result with number in the OP:

```
$ g++ -O3 prime1.cpp
$ time ./a.out 
71
839
1471
6857

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comment: What is the meaning of primeFlagger = vector<char>(root + 1, true);? why did you put root+1?

Comment: and what is the purpose of #define Sieve?

Comment: The purpose of '#define SIEVE' that is commented presently is to enable one implementation or another. The vector is allocated for `root + 1` elements as in `C++` all indices are zero-based and allocation of `N` elements means allocation of elements with indices from 0 through N-1. We need an element with index root to be allocated as well, hence `root+1`

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but you try different implementations to find out which one is faster? (Sieve vs. no sieve)?

Comment: and then in the main loop you do {
            m /= 2;
        } while (m % 2 == 0); because you want to make m smaller?

Comment: yes. and I leaved the code conditionally switched off to the one who would like to play with it. As for `/=2` and `/=i` - yes, as soon as a factor is found the number has to be reduced by that factor.

Comment: Ok, but in the first part, why is it only pfactors.push_back(2)? how does the program know if it should be 4, 6, 8, etc.? Won't it add just 2 every time?

Comment: 4, 6, 8 - are not primes, why it should add them?

Comment: it not only does push_back(2). check the code carefully

Answer (score 0):

600851475143 is a *very* large number and your algorithm is *very* inefficient. I suspect that it would eventually terminate, but that "eventually" is far beyond the time you'd be willing to wait.

The above is assuming that `long long` on your platform is even capable of representing the number - if it is only 32bits then it is not.

What you really need is a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Ok. Here's one hint: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes there are better options still, but that's not a bad place to start reading.

Comment: the problem of Sieve algorithm is that it takes a lot of memory. Here it can be done. You need 1Gb of data to compute primes up to 1 billion. 600851475143 is 6E12: trillion => square root: 1E7 : can be done. Without sieve, you wait forever for the prime list computation.

Comment: I did not say it was the *best* option. Nor the *only* one. Simply that it would be a good place for OP to start research.

Comment: Re: " if [`long long`] is only 32bits" -- `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits wide.

Answer (score 0):

your program fails because you are using `int` data type. It has `32 bits, i.e 2^32 ~= 9 digits max`

To access some values greater than 9 digits, try using `long long` or `unsigned long long`. It has `64 bits, i.e 2^64 ~= 18 digits for signed and 20 digits for unsigned`.

Edit: ^This is for C++ 98 (Orwell Dev C++: Tested)

```
vector<int> pfactor;
```

This int on vector is making your program fail. And you don't need to reserve any space in a vector since its dynamic unless you are working on 2d Vectors.

Example Code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool ifPrime ( int number ) {
    for ( long long int i=2; i<sqrt(number); ++i ) {
        if ( number%i == 0 ) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main ( ) {
    long long int number = 600851475143;
    static long long int largestPrime;

    bool found = false;
    for ( long long int i=sqrt(number); i>=0 && !found; i=i-1 ) {
        if ( number%i==0 && ifPrime(i) ) {
            largestPrime = i;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    cout << "Largest Prime for " << number << " is: " << largestPrime << endl;
}
```

Comment: The size of `int` is platform dependant. It can be both smaller and larger than 32bit (although it is guaranteed to be at least 16bit).

Comment: and the problem is not only that but performance here. sqrt(number) holds in a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Edited @JesperJuhl

Comment: Give it a try then, your doubts will be cleared :) @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: I gave, the output is: "Largest Prime for 600851475143 is: 6857"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the problem here is that in this particular case the maximum prime divisor is much much less than the original number. what if we have to find the same answer for a  `some_big_prime_greater_than_10bln*2`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123074/discussion-between-jean-francois-fabre-and-serge).

Comment: This answer is wrong. It works there, but let's take a big prime and try the program on `2*p`: the program will find `2` as the greatest prime number. I gave a wrong answer and deleted it. The right way to go is find prime factors and divide the number on-the-fly as Serge did.